# Как перенаправить несколько доменов на один?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Здравствуйте, как сделать переадресацию (*.htaccess*) с доменов (шт. 10 и они не мои и постоянно увеличиваются не знаю почему) на один домен.

То есть все эти домена `1сайт.ru` `2сайт.ru` `3сайт.ru` прикрепили к моему *ip*, нужно перенаправлялись на `сайт.ru`

Comment: Эти домены на вашей учетной записи хостинга находятся? вы их владелец?

Comment: Они вообще не мои их прикрепили к моему ip и при заходе с другого домена попадают на мой, и я хочу сделать переадресацию на свой домен.

Comment: @G-Force53 А как вы узнаете что они стали направлены на вас ?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*domen\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domen.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```